# Python argparse default string value

Tags: python, argparse

using `argparse`:

```
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Log to file")
```

I want to achieve the following behavior:

1. The user doesn't specify the `-o` flag - no logging should be done.
2. User specifies the `-o` with nothing - I should log to a default location, 
   defined within my program.
3. User specifies `-o` and a string(path) - I should log there.

Does anyone know the best way to use `add_argument` to achieve that? I saw a [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997933/how-to-make-an-optional-value-for-argument-using-argparse) with int values, but in my case, it doesn't get my default value.

Comment: Do you understand why the example gets a `int` value?  The role of the `type` parameter?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`nargs='?'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) for this:

```
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', 
                    nargs='?', default=None, const='my_default_location')
```

If not present, it will produce the `default` value, if present but without a value it'll use `const`, otherwise it'll use the supplied value.

Also read through the other examples in the docs, there's a sample for an optional output file which could be useful.